# Cardinal of $\prod_{n}^{}2^n$

Tags: cardinals

what is the cardinal of $\prod_{n}^{}2^n$?

I tried to create an injective function from this formula to the natural numbers and stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{\{1,2,\dots, n\}}$?

Comment: Over what does your $n$ range? And is $2^n$ meant to be the set or the (integer) function?

Comment: That's because you can't.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, and while it is not word-for-word a duplicate, the answers work almost entirely out of the box to this question. So the banner's "This question already has an answer" is  quite accurate.